# getView() returns NULL in zend framework 2 Custom Form View Helper

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view, view-helpers

Trying to get the view object from a view helper so I can render a certain partial. but All I get is NULL
here is the code
namespace App\Form\View\Helper;

```
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput;
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
class FormDate2 extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $script = 'element-decorators/date-picker';

    public function render(ElementInterface $element, $formType = null, array $displayOptions = array())
    {
        echo '<pre>';var_dump($this->getView());echo '</pre>';die();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you testing the helper to determine that the view object is null?

Comment: Custom Element using that helper

Comment: The process is as follows, a FormRow Helper renders the element view parts, and getting the element html through the element's helper which is the one posted above

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, Not sure if it is the best one, If anyone got a better one please post above

Here it goes, retrieve the view renderer from the Di

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        if($this->getView() == NULL){
            $di = new Di();
            $view = $di->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');
            $this->setView($view);
        }
    }
```